# A pseudo-riley?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge

<sub>This is my first puzzle, so feedback welcome!</sub>

I wanted to be the very best, so here are six legendary rileys for you to solve.

> 1. My prefix is a mythical creature; my infix has went away, but missing the end of time; my suffix is at the end of many minerals and stones.
> 2. My prefix is like a cruel ruler; my infix is a version me; my suffix is a dark, flammable liquid.
> 3. My prefix is like a lizard, but only half of it; my infix is a version i; my suffix is close to menace, but lacking a ...
> 4. My prefix describes new encounter with somebody; my infix is used to hold another attention; my suffix is something that is revolting
> 5. My prefix is two letters for a state; my infix is something curvy; my suffix happens when I'm very hungry
> 6. My prefix is something sticky; my infix makes my prefix great; my suffix is like an Egyptian god.

Comment: Do the 6 answers relate to lead to a final answer?

Comment: @CinCout They do not. Just 6 standard rileys :)

Comment: Even new users know about Riley? Riley you're famous!

Comment: I guess this should rather have been separated in 6 different questions, but since there is already an answer addressing all the rileys, I think we better leave it as it is. (when will 'riley' enter official dictionaries?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My prefix is a mythical creature; my infix has went away, but missing the end of time; my suffix is at the end of many minerals and stones.

> Dragonite - Dragon, gone [remove e], and ite

My prefix is like a cruel ruler; my infix is a version me; my suffix is a dark, flammable liquid.

> Tyranitar - Tyrant, I, and Tar

My prefix is like a lizard, but only half of it; my infix is a version i; my suffix is close to menace, but lacking a ...

> Salamence - Salamander, me, and menance (ce)

My prefix describes new encounter with somebody; my infix is used to hold another attention; my suffix is something that is revolting

> Metagross - Met, aggro [agro], Gross

My prefix is two letters for a state; my infix is something curvy; my suffix happens when I'm very hungry

> Garchomp - GA, arch (curvy), Chomp

My prefix is something sticky; my infix makes my prefix great; my suffix is like an Egyptian god.

> Goodra - Goo, [add a d to make good] and Ra

Relevance to title:

> These are all pseudo-legendary Pokemon

Comment: And the connection to the title is that rot13(gurfr ner nyy cfrhqb-yrtraqnel Cbxrzba)

Comment: @PiIsNot3 right, I forgot to put that in there